# show that $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} M^4_s] = \frac43 \mathbb{E}[M_t \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} M^3_s] $

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

> Show that $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} M^4_s] = \frac43 \mathbb{E}[M_t \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} M^3_s] $,
>   where $M = (M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a non-negative, continuous martingale starting from $0$.

I have already shown that :

$a \mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a) = \mathbb{E}[M_t \mathbb{1}_{\{ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a \}} ] \,\,\, \forall (a, t) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{+} - \{0,0\}$

It's supposed to help me prove the equality in the title.

So I integrated both sides :

\begin{align} & \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty} 2a \mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a) da =\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[M_t \mathbb{1}_{\{ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a \}} ]  da \\ 
\iff & \frac12 \mathbb{E}[(\sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s)^2] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[M_t \mathbb{1}_{\{ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a \}} ]  da \\
\iff &  \frac12 \mathbb{E}[\sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s^2] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[M_t \mathbb{1}_{\{ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} M_s \geq a \}} ]  da \\ \end{align}

Since the property of being a martingale is weakened down to being just a sub-martingale when squaring the martingale then we can't replace $M$ by $M^2$ and thus I don't how else to make the to the fourth power term appear, I also have no idea how to deal with the RHS.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: The $4/3$  intuits than the proof of Doob's inequality (Lp case) might help....

Comment: @Sesame We need an equality here though, not just an inequality.

Comment: "a *positive*, continuous martingale starting from $0$" does not exist.

Comment: @zhoraster you mean except the trivial a.e. zero martingale ? it's true I can't think of one on the spot but I fail why it shouldn't exist.

Comment: @zhoraster I was just about to comment the same thing. Even a nonnegative, continuous martingale starting at $0$ is identically $0$.

Comment: It doesn’t exist because $0$ is not positive.

Comment: @user658409 yeah sorry about that, I study in french notation, positive means "nonnegative"

Comment: Actually, I believe the word "positive" or "nonnegative" is redundant here (see @user658409's answer, which imo should be just a comment); just write $(\sup M_s)^4$, and the equality should be true. Here is a hint for you: if a random variable $X$ is a.s. non-negative, and $f$ is continuously differentiable and non-decreasing with $f(0)=0$, then 
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_0^\infty f'(x) \mathbb{P}(X\ge x) dx.
$$

Comment: @zhoraster How can we prove that $$\mathbb E[f(X)] = \int_0^\infty f'(x)\mathbb P(X\geqslant x)\ \mathsf dx\quad \mathrm? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M_t$ is a nonnegative continuous martingale starting from $0$ then $M_t\equiv 0$ a.s. for all $t$ and thus both sides are $0$.

Comment: Would you care to provide some verification for this claim?